# How I can stop my script execute if external script not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object **Checkout** that I invoke from external script, 
some times when I invoke it, I get erorr masage `Checkout is not defined` because I think this object loaded before external script.
Is there a way to fix this error

external script

```
<script src="https://example.com/checkout.js"></script>
```

my script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    Checkout.dosomething();
});
```

Comment: You'd be ***far*** better off fixing the intermittent loading issue instead of putting a band-aid fix on this. Surely this script is essential for page functionality - what are you expecting to happen if the script isn't available, other than to sweep the error under the rug. If the order of the scripts is the issue, address that instead.

Comment: please don't forget to accept the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to order script loading in such a way that the dependant script would be loaded after the dependencies load.

As a workaround, you can check if the dependency is accessible inside your script.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (!Checkout) {
        return;
    }
    Checkout.dosomething();
});
```